# Laravel: call class methods from php script in public directory

Tags: php, class, laravel, public

I have a view.blade.php that calls a wrapper.php that return some value for an iframe in the view.

I'm able to return that value, but I have to do some work with other methods in my laravel classes.

It's possible to instatiate the classes inside the wrapper php and call methods, or call static class methods?

Project structure:

```
- project
-- app
--- Http
---- Classes
----- RepositoryUtil.php
...
-- public
--- Wrapper.php
...
-- resources
--- views
---- partials
----- view.blade.php
```

Code inside view.blade.php:

```
<iframe id="reader" src="/libs/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=http://project.dev/Wrapper.php?id={{$encrypted}}">
</iframe>
```

Code inside Wrapper.php:

```
<?php
// tried: use App\Http\Classes\RepositoryUtil
// tried: \App\Http\Classes\RepositoryUtil::getValue();
// tried: {{RepositoryUtil::getValue()}}
$myValue = RepositoryUtil::getValue(); #not work

var_dump($myValue);
?>
```

Code inside RepositoryUtil.php

```
<?php

class RepositoryUtil{
    public static function getValue(){
        dd("getValue!");
        return "value";
    }
}

?>
```

The error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'RepositoryUtil' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/project/public/Wrapper.php on line 14
```

---

EDIT:
I can call static class method adding `include_once("../App/Http/Classes/RepositoryUtil.php");` at the top of `Wrapper.php` but when I call the "laravel methods" like `$decrypted = Crypt::decrypt($encrypted);` it return the error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Class 'Crypt' not found in /home/vagrant/Code/project/App/Http/Classes/RepositoryUtil.php on line 13
```

[image: Error]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After many and many attemps and research, I figure that out!

Post my Wrapper.php code:

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$value = RepositoryUtil::getValue();

// Your other staff here... 

?>
```

The problem was that after calling external php, Laravel wasn't booted!

I tried to boot with `require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';`, `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';` and calling `$app->boot()`, and it worked.

But there were other problems: Facades were not loaded, but I can see into "alias" array when log `$app` variable.
You have to boot kernel to get Facades back.

Using `Laravel 5.1`.